# Which function to kill: Sine or Cos?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, trigonometry, exponential-function, approximation

I got an equation which was a solution to some familiar Differential Equation I am solving, the solution takes the form of:

$$V=Ce^{-ix}$$

but

$$Ce^{-ix}=A\cos(x)+B\sin(x)$$

so

$$V=A\cos(x)+B\sin(x)$$

Typically, evaluating the equation above involves killing either the $\cos$ term or $\sin$ term, or keeping both.

My question is, how do we know which function to kill or to keep?

Comment: Usually it depends on what your initial condition is if I understand your question correctly

Comment: For linear second-order differential equations, you'll have two independent coefficients that need to be determined by the initial conditions (e.g., by $V(0)$ and $V'(0)$).

Comment: $e^{-ix}=\cos(x)-i\sin(x)$ no need for A and B. But what you may have is $Ae^{-ix}$

Comment: It's not clear to me what you are asking. The unique values of $A,B$ which make your second equation true are $A=1$, $B=-i$: $$e^{-ix} = \cos(x) - i \, \sin(x)$$

Comment: ok, now updated, yes, I agree, killing the function depends on the initial conditions, so now, what conditions apply so that we can kill, say the cos term, or the sine term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the differential equation itself is unchanged by complex conjugation (i.e. all coefficients are real) then if $e^{-ix}$ is a solution then so is its complex conjugate $e^{ix}$.  (Here I'm assuming $x$ is real; if it's not then the foregoing sentence needs emendation.)

If it's a *linear* differential equation then $$Ae^{ix}+Be^{-ix} \tag 1$$ is a solution, for any two complex numbers $A$ and $B$.

Now let's suppose you want *real* solutions.  Then you have
\begin{align}
Ae^{ix}+Be^{-ix} & = A(\cos x+i\sin x)+B(\cos x-i\sin x) \\[6pt]
& = (A+B)\cos x + i(A-B)\sin x \\[6pt]
& = C\cos x + D\sin x. \tag 2
\end{align}
This is real if and only if
\begin{align}
A+B & = C \text{ is real, and} \\[6pt]
i(A-B) & = D \text{ is real.}
\end{align}
In order that $A+B$ be real, it is necessary and sufficient that the complex parts of $A$ and $B$ cancel out when added.

In order that $i(A-B)$ be real, it is necessary and sufficient that $A-B$ be a pure imaginary, so the real parts of $A$ and $B$ cancel out when subtracted.

This $A$ and $B$ must be complex conjugates of each other.  That is equivalent to $C$ and $D$ in $(2)$ above being real.

Either $(1)$ or $(2)$ gives the same set of solutions if $A,B,C,D$ are allowed to be arbitrary complex numbers.

If you want to know *all* solutions, then that's what you need.  If you want a particular solution satisfying specified initial conditions, then you need to find the values of $A$ and $B$, or of $C$ and $D$, that satisfy those conditions.

For example if $y(0)=1$ and $y'(0)=0$, then you need $C=1$ and $D=0$.

Comment: Ok, I think I get it now, so its Either C or D would be real and not both? Since by default A and B are Complex, that means C is Complex, so if that is the case, $cos$ term usually is killed because its multiplied with a complex number? Can you confirm my understanding?

Comment: $C$ and $D$ would both be real if the solution is real. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: You would "kill" terms only to satisfy initial conditions.  $A$, $B$, $C$, and $D$ are complex and that means they may be real.  $C$ and $D$ are real if the solution is real.

Comment: I guess I got the wrong assumptions, so if in case the initial conditions tells that at x=0, y is 0, that gives C = 0 & D = 1, since only Sine Graph has an initial condition located at y=0?

Comment: Yes. ${{\qquad}}$